# Android switch to next item based on time

Tags: android

I am trying to display bookings based on their start and end time. Let's say I have 2 bookings:

- A: 27/5/2021 16:00 - 27/5/2021 16:15
- B: 27/5/2021 16:15 - 27/5/2021 16:30

Now when its 15:59 I can see that the next booking is A so when its 16:00 it shows that current booking is A and next is B. Once the time passes past 16:15 it displays current as B and next is empty.

So now I am wondering how can I make sure that it switches the active booking with the next booking once that time has been reached.

At first, I was thinking to use some kind of listener that would listen to the time of the actual device and would check if now() is greater than the time of the next booking.

Except that I would rather have this being checked every minute, instead of constantly.
Problem is I have no clue how it's possible to implement this.

Thus, my question is how do you implement something like this, or what is the best way to do this?

Thanks in advance,

Billy Cottrell

Comment: Cannot a booking C be done between start and end time of booking A?

Comment: Take a look at reactive programming (e.g. RxJava, Kotlin Flow), it might help.

Comment: @blackapps In the scenario that we would be deploying these bookings can't overlap each other.

Comment: @m0skit0 good to know, I'll take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use RXjava for this.

Suppose you need to run the updater function after 15 mins to update the current booking
the code should be like this:

```
Observable.interval(15,TimeUnit.MINUTES)
.doOnNext(p->YOUR_CURRENT_BOOKING_UPDATION())
 .subscribe()
```

Now, we may need to update after some arbitrary amount of time, so to overcome this we will calculate the interval `Starting time - Ending Time` and assign it to a variable , then instead or using hardcoded value`15` use `Observable.interval(YOUR_VARIABLE,TimeUnit.MINUTES)`

**Note : Replace YOUR_CURRENT_BOOKING_UPDATION()** with the real function

**Feel free to ask if something is unclear**

Comment: Hi @kamal-nayan this seems like it might be the solution for this, but I am worried that it might make the application run slower in the long run. This is because the application will run constantly during the office hours so that if it runs from 08:00 till 17:00 and refreshes every 15 minutes it will have to refresh 36 times a day which I guess is okay. Except that the user is able to change the synchronization frequency to as low as every minute meaning with the office hours I mentioned it would synchronize 540 times a day and I don't know if it can handle that without slowing down.

Comment: All these tasks are performed on background thread, as far as I know. So, I think this will not lead to ANR or make slow the app. Check about RXJava